# Flot chart inside jqueryui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flot

I'm using jqueryui to display my page content in tabs. Right now I have only one tab, with a placeholder div inside. This div displays a [flot chart](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/basic.html), which has a fixed size. Problem is that jqueryui doesn't detect the size of the placeholder div, so my flot graph does not look like it's inside the tab.

Is it possible to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the width and height on your placeholder div to the same width and height that your graph will be. If you need, you can do that dynamically with javascript before you call the $.tabs() function, and it will still work.

Comment: Thank you. I specified the dimensions for the *tab div* to be the same size as the flot chart. Then it worked!